# PHP include: How to include an external php file on a certain place in the html document

Tags: php, html, include, location

I have the following code

```
$content .= '
<div id="myDivID">';
    include 'search.php';
$content .= '
</div>';
```

But the included file is on top of the page. I want the output in between `myDivID`. Do I have an error in the php script or does the include always put it on top of the page?

Comment: Is it just VISUALLY on top of the page? If you look at the source of the page (view-source in browser), does the output of search.php appear in the right place? You may have some CSS that forces whatever's in search.php to jump to the top of the page, even though it's physically located within the div.

Comment: It's not just visually it's also in the html output. There it is outside of the `myDivID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is correct

```
echo '<div id="myDivID">';
    include 'search.php';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it seems it's correct. The reason is I used a variable which contains the output of the whole php file. Because the include is outside of the variable input, it is put on top of the page. Though I didn't managed to find out where `$content`is echoed ..

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="myDivID">
    <?php require_once('search.php'); ?>
</div>
```